# Is it possible to get a list of all groups I am a member of with the graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the title asks is it possible to get a list of all groups I am a member of with the graph api? I can't find anything in the docs but it seems odd that this endpoint would not be made available.

In my case I'm developing a tool that alerts the user when a post containing specific keywords is posted to a group they are a member of. The flow goes like this:

1. User accepts app permissions
2. All groups are compiled into a list
3. User selects the groups they want to monitor for specific posts
4. I use their token to periodically check their selected groups for posts that match the keyword/s. If a match is found an email/sms is sent out to the user alerting them of the matched post.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get a list of groups you manage, there is no way to get a list of groups you are just a member of anymore. The `user_groups` permission got removed, there is only `user_managed_groups` now.

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, btw. If it´s not possible with the Graph API, it´s most likely not allowed.

Comment: @BugHunterUK: please don´t remove the part about scraping, it´s very important for the answer. People need to know if stuff they want to do is not allowed, and you did mention scraping in your question.

Comment: The line regarding scraping in my question was not relevant. I have removed it.